# scroll an UIScrollView in another UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have 2 nested UIScrollView instances. They both enable page scrolling & bounces. The inner scroll view and outer scroll view can both perform correct behavior when scrolling.

The only problem is when I scroll the inner scroll view to its border of content, the bounce effect is missing. The effect is replaced by the outer scroll view starts to scrolling.

I want keep the bounce effect in the inner scroll view.

How can I achieve it? Thanks in advanced.

I think a demo can more precisely describe my problem, so I wrote the demo code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView * outer = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    outer.pagingEnabled = YES;
    outer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300 * 3, 460);
    outer.bounces = YES;
    outer.scrollEnabled = YES;
    outer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIScrollView * inner = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 200)];
    inner.pagingEnabled = YES;
    inner.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320 * 3, 200);
    inner.bounces = YES;
    inner.scrollEnabled = YES;
    inner.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

    [outer addSubview:inner];
    [self.view addSubview:outer];

}
```

Comment: One option you can do is in scrollview delegate, disable the userinteraction for outerscrollview when the inner one is still scrolling. Only once it is stopped, the userinteraction should be enabled for outer one.

Comment: I don't understand completely: If the bounce in the inner should work then i wonder when should the outer start to scroll? Can you please explain?

Comment: @rockstarberlin because my inner scroll view is small than the outer one, so user can touch the outer scroll view directly to scroll it.

Comment: @ACB Thanks. I've tested this method before posting the question. It can NOT work because when user start to scroll the inner one to enable bounces effect, the - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView delegate method of inner won't be called. I don't know why...

Comment: @tangqiaoboy, never heard of that. Are you setting the delegate and all correctly? Ideally it should call.